# How to remove comma inside a double quotes in a CSV File?

Tags: csv, parsing

If i have a row like this.
536381,82567,"AIRLINE LOUNGE,METAL SIGN",2,12/1/2010 9:41,2.1,15311,United Kingdom

How do i get the output like this:
536381,82567,"AIRLINE LOUNGE METAL SIGN",2,12/1/2010 9:41,2.1,15311,United Kingdom

Answer (score 1):

Since the program being used has not been specifically mentioned, a general solution would be to parse first, replace the comma with space, and save again as a csv file.

As an example, I would open this CSV in Excel, Use REPLACE to replace the "'" with " ", and then save again as a CSV.

Same could be done with any programming language which can parse a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using any programming language to extract this record then you might use the replace operation to remove "," with the space.
Like in Java `String.replace(","," ");`

Comment: HI, please can you help with this in java only.

Comment: Are you doing this extract from any DB?

Comment: Reading from a file.

Comment: So to do this we need to read the line by characters.
(Code will have some error as i am doing this on mobile)
BufferReader br = new bufferReader(csvfile);
String str= br.readLine();
Boolean check= false;
StringBuilder sb= new StringBuilder ();
For(int i =0;i<str.length;i++){
If(check==false) {
If(str[i]=='"'){
sb.append(str);
check=true;
}
}
else {
sb.append(str.replace(',', ' ');
If(str[i]=='"'){
check= false;
}
}
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());